# How to disable ScreenShare on MediaProjection API but keep recording to save as MP4

Tags: java, android, screen-capture, android-mediaprojection

I want to make a screen capture app with a notification tool bar on top like AZ Recorder or DU Recorder. From the examples i see online on how to use the new API MediaProjection they use ScreenShare enabled which prompts like you are projecting to another screen and you can see the broadcast symbol on your notification bar area. Is there anyway i can disable this feature on android while using MediaProjection API or is there another API I could use.

I don't want this to show up. The user will know that they are recording but why does that broadcast symbol show?
[image]

Comment: If you are asking how to record the screen without the user knowing, AFAIK that is not possible on modern versions of Android, except perhaps with root.

Comment: I updated my question with an image. They know they are recording because they enabled recording, thats the purpose of the app is to record there screen for there own use.

Comment: First, users forget. Second, users might not know when you start and stop recording. Since screen recording has major privacy and security ramifications, Android wants to increase the likelihood that the user realizes that the recording is going on.